# Boolean output inconsisten

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python if

```
a = 1
b = 1
print(a is b)
```

returns True.

However, if

```
c = 1.23
d = 1.23

print(c is d)
```

returns False.

It appears for the float data type the output is False. Can someone explain to me why does python behave this way?

```
a = 1
b = 1

print(a is b)
#Output: True

c = 1.23
d = 1.23
print(c is d)
#Output: False
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> print(a is b)
True
>>> c = 1.2
>>> d = 1.2
>>> print(c is d)
False
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x77fb6c20'
>>> hex(id(b))
'0x77fb6c20'
>>> hex(id(c))
'0x2185c8e1990'
>>> hex(id(d))
'0x2185c8e1a38'
>>> a = 900
>>> b = 900
>>> print(a is b)
False
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x2185d434e10'
>>> hex(id(b))
'0x2185d434eb0'
>>>
```

As you can see here when `a` and `b` are `1`,  the memory location of the variables is same as they are cached by the python runtime. `c` and `d` are referred at different memory locations due to their data type being float. When we take a large value for `a` and `b`, their memory location is different.
`is` statement in python isn't a comparison operator but tells if the variables referred are bound to the same objects.

As per [here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all
>   integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you
>   actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it
>   should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behaviour
>   of Python in this case is undefined. :-)

Comment: please do [do not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)!

Comment: There is no code. It is an output.

Comment: [do not post code (and output) as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)! (is `print(a is b)` not code?) ...did you read the link i posted?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Because the Python runtime caches some small integers so that they can be reused. Other numbers aren't cached, and require object allocation each time one is created. `is` tests if two objects are the same object, not just two objects with the same numerical value.

You should not rely on this optimisation. Always test numerical equality with `==`.